# Toggle and change dynamically the id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-selectors, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter  Bootstrap with jQuery

and i was wondering how can i toggle between "Subscribe / UnSubscribe"

Each click its an ajax request   so the user can Subscribe /  UnSubscribe

Once a user subscribed i display a messege "Subscribed!"
What about if a user regret and want to unubscribed?

I would like to have in one button both functionality.
I am changing the id dynamically but it doent work!

```
button class="btn" id="subscribe" data-toggle="button" data-loading-text="Loading..."  data-complete-text="Subscribed!">Subscribe
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#subscribe').button();
        $('#unsubscribe').button();
    });




    $('#unsubscribe').click(function () {   
        $('#unsubscribe').button('loading');

        $.ajax({
            url: "<%= "#{root_url}unsubscribe_from/#{@collection.id}"%>" ,
            type: "GET",
            data: "",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#unsubscribe').button('complete');
                jQuery("#unsubscribe").attr("id","subscribe");
                jQuery("#subscribe").attr("data-complete-text").text("Subscribed!");
                }});
                return false;

            });


$('#subscribe').click(function () {   
    $('#subscribe').button('loading');
    // $('#subscribe').button('reset');
    $.ajax({
        url: "<%= "#{root_url}subscribe_to/#{@collection.id}"%>" ,
        type: "GET",
        data: "",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#subscribe').button('complete');
            jQuery("#subscribe").attr("id","unsubscribe");
            jQuery("#unsubscribe").attr("data-complete-text").text("Unsubscribe!");
            }});
            return false;

        });
```

Comment: You don't really need to change the id. If you had a single click handler for the button, within that handler you could check the current button text and take the appropriate action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#subscribe, #unsubscribe', function(){
    var url; 
    var button_id; 
    var button_text; 
    var self = $(this);  
    self.button('loading');

   if( this.id === 'subscribe' )
    {
        url = "<%= "#{root_url}subscribe_to/#{@collection.id}"%>"; 
        button_id = 'unsubscribe';
        button_text = 'Subscribed!';  
    }
    else 
    {
        url = "<%= "#{root_url}unsubscribe_from/#{@collection.id}"%>"; 
        button_id = 'subscribe'; 
        button_text = 'Unsubscribed!'; 
    }

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        data: "",
        success: function(data) {
               self.button('complete');
               self.attr("id", button_id);
               self.attr("data-complete-text", button_text).text(button_text);
            }});
            return false;

      });
})
```

Comment: thank you.. this is what i want :) the only think doent work its

$('#'+button_id).attr("data-complete-text").text(button_text);

but i think it should be 

self.text(button_text);
self.attr("data-complete-text", button_text);

Comment: Ah yes, that's what i had before, i changed it. Please mark as answered when you get the chance, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is happening at present is your click handler is getting attached at the start only. So later changing the id will not attach the handler. For this you use dynamic handler.

So you should do following

```
$(document).on("click", "#subscribe", function(){ 
  // ...
});  

$(document).on("click", "#unsubscribe", function(){ 
  // ...
});
```

See [JQuery On](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more details. Earlier you would have used [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: +1 However earlier versions should use `.delegate()` not `.live()` per jQuery documentation.